# Nexus 4 wont charge or turn on; LED is blinking red

Tags: charging, nexus-4

I've been charging my Nexus with the original charger for 2 hours. It still shows red LED light when I hold the power button. I've tried everything:

- Different USB chargers
- Holding the volume button with the power button

It just wont work. I'm not the original owner so I can't get another one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to long press power in for about 30s.
Then short press.

This is how I recover after a Nexus4 crash.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Nexus may not be getting enough power. Check out this [related article](https://support.google.com/nexus/7/answer/2668668?hl=en&ref_topic=2840575) (for Nexus 7) that sounds like your problem:

Since you are not the original owner, and not under any warranty, perhaps you'd like to try some DIY work. In this case, check out [this article](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2250454).

Good luck! I hope this can help you.

Comment: Ive been charging it from more than 12 hours. Still the red light blinks and then goes off. Im worried. And i cant open up my phone.

Comment: And also if i use the iphone charger theres a steady red light and if i use the original charger then the light turns on then starts to blink. Whats this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Possibility 1 (worst case scenario) -  since you're not the original owner, you don't know what the previous owner did. In that case it can happen that he/she might have had experimented a bit and formatted the nand or the phone malfunctioned and somehow the nand got formatted i.e full clean no bios(download mode as in android). In this case, your phone is bricked. You can possibly bring it back if you have experience with rooting, custom rom flashing all that stuff.  Plus you will need the restore bootloader file for the nexus. I had experimented this: nand formatting on my galaxy s3 showed the same behaviour. Go to the [XDA-Forums](http://www.xda-developers.com/) and search. If you don't have any experience and don't know what I am talking about, I'd suggest taking the phone to a service center.

Possibility 2 (good scenario compared to the previous one) - battery is dead since the nexus's battery is inaccessible: the same solution here, also take it to a service centre.